# Nginx welcome page showing up rather than the landing page

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I deployed my Django project on Digital Ocean using this guide (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04), I completed the steps shown in the guide and all of them seem to run without any error on the terminal still when I type the IP address of the website the Nginx welcome page shows up.

The website was working fine up to this command (`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 NGOsamyak.wsgi`) after configuring Ngnix the problem occurred.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/NGOsamyak

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 165.22.216.110;


location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
root /home/samyakbvs/NGOsamyak-project;
}


location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/samyakbvs/NGOsamyak-project/NGOsamyak.sock;
}
}
```

Picture of the terminal log : [image]

Picture of the welcome page : [image]

Comment: Have you created a link of this conf file to sites-enabled directory? Have you reloaded nginx service?

Comment: Where is the site-enabled directory located and how to add the link of this file to it?

Comment: `sudo ln` is the command. It looks like you've missed a space. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed a space in the command `sudo ln`

> sudo ln -s
>   /etc/nginx/sites-available/NGOsamyak/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

That should be

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/NGOsamyak /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Run `sudo nginx -t` to verify everything is correct.

Then finally run `sudo systemctl restart nginx`